# How to access linux bluetooth stack with java

Tags: java, linux, bluetooth

I'm trying to make java application that discovers nearby bluetooth devices and get incoming data from them. And I absolutely don't know how to do it. My application is for getting data from microcontroller board with bluetooth module. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bluetooth stack like Bluecove libraries implementation which supports JSR-82 capble phone device. You can use it's deviceagent discovery api to discover bluetooth devices.